# Raspberry Pi hangs on USB activation

Tags: usb

I try to run gentoo on my Raspberry Pi. Kernel 4.1.15. After booting kernel loads & try to discovery hardware. On USB activation all hangs. These are last strings I see in console:

```
[    2.219170] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    2.227820] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.240352] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.246298] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    2.523857] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    2.634324] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    2.643335] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

I use 5V 2A power source connected to GPIO power pins, voltmeter shows 4.9V between these pins.

What a trouble can it be?

**UPD**: The problem was in myself: I just copied string running getty on RPi's UART, and there was: `getty`, but should be `agetty`.

Now it works fine. But unlike of Raspbian disappears all output between init starts & agetty runs.

Comment: What do you have connected to the USB ports?

Comment: Nothing, they are empty. Boot hangs on discovering of the network card. I have two RPis and this problem detected on both, so, I think that the problem can be in my kernel.

Comment: That's veird: I change my kernel and modules to precompiled from here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/  and have the same trouble.

Comment: A try to boot with old raspbian, but new kernel (4.1.15) was succeed. So the problem is not with kernel or power. Something wrong with stage3.